# AES CBC PKCS5 Decryption in WIndows 8 Appstore application

Tags: android, encryption, windows-8, aes

Well its embarrassing to ask this question despite having lot of articles related to this in web, but I could not figure it out.I am struck with this one.

I am encrypting a text in Android using `AES/CBC/PKCS5` algorithm but I could not decrypt it in windows 8 appstore application.Here is my encryption code

```
public static String encrypt(String plainText,String password) throws Exception {

    // convert key to bytes
    byte[] keyBytes = password.getBytes("UTF-8");
    // Use the first 16 bytes (or even less if key is shorter)

    byte[] keyBytes16 = new byte[16];

    System.arraycopy(keyBytes, 0, keyBytes16, 0,
            Math.min(keyBytes.length, 16));

    // convert plain text to bytes
    byte[] plainBytes = plainText.getBytes("UTF-8");

    // setup cipher
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes16, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    byte[] iv = new byte[16]; // initialization vector with all 0
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(iv));

    // encrypt
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(plainBytes);
    String encryptedString = Base64.encodeToString(
            cipher.doFinal(plainBytes), Base64.NO_WRAP);
    // encryptedString

    return Base64.encodeToString(encrypted, Base64.NO_WRAP);
}
```

I am encrypting using the following code in windows 8 application

```
public string AES_Encrypt(string input, string pass)
{
  SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider SAP = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesCbcPkcs7);

  string encrypted = "";
  try
  {
    byte[] test1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pass);
    byte[] test2 = new byte[16];

    for (int i = 0; i < test1.Length;i++ )
    {
      test2[i] = test1[i];
    }

    CryptographicKey key =
    SAP.CreateSymmetricKey(CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(test2));

    IBuffer Buffer = CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
    encrypted = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(key, Buffer, null));

    return encrypted;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    return null;
  }
}
```

following is the decryption algo

```
public string AES_Decrypt(string input, string pass)
{

  SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider SAP = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesCbcPkcs7);

  string decrypted = "";

  try
  {
    byte[] test1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pass);
    byte[] test2 = new byte[16];

    for (int i = 0; i < test1.Length;i++ )
    {
      test2[i] = test1[i];
    }

    CryptographicKey key = 
        SAP.CreateSymmetricKey(CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(test2));


    IBuffer Buffer = CryptographicBuffer.DecodeFromBase64String(input);
    byte[] Decrypted;

    CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(CryptographicEngine.Decrypt(key, Buffer, null), out Decrypted);
    decrypted = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Decrypted, 0, Decrypted.Length);
    return decrypted;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    return null;
  }
}
```

I know that there is something wrong with the IV being generated. If I give the Iv as `null`, the decryption algorithm generates some result(though it is wrong), If i give some values for IV, it throws an exception such as "**Value does not fall within the expected range.**"

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please remove the MD5 code from your second code example. It's confusing and it's not being used.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < test1.Length;i++ )` <-- this is a bug. You should be comparing with `test2.Length`. Also, **where is your decryption algorithm**? You've just posted two encryption routines.

Comment: Removed MD5 code. I thought that length of the key should be minimum of 16 characters. test1 contains the actual password.if test1 length is less than 16, then rest should be filled with empty values.I will post the decryption algo now.

Comment: In that case, try having the for loop check of `i < test1.Length && i < test2.Length;`.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply.test2 is already initialized(byte[] test2 = new byte[16]) so I dont think the additional check is needed.test1 will be copied to test2 and for the rest of bytes will be the empty values assigned during initailization.Decrypt routine is added.

Comment: If `test1` is larger than sixteen bytes, you will have an exception. Trust me - that piece of code is currently broken.

Comment: ok got your point.The password length is always 4 characters in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the transformation from Android to Windows but I noticed in the JAva you are using PKCS5 and in C# PKCS7.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no PKCS7 in java.